# Get item from sublist with another sublist containing indexes

Tags: python, list

I am struggling with sublists, I would like to get items from list at indexes given in index_list where these indexes are also in sublist. I would like to also keep the structure. What is the best method to do that? Should I use zip() ?

```
list = [['a','b','c'],['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c']]

index_list = [[0,2],[1,2,3],[1,2]]
```

Comment: why would you use zip? do you know what it does? did you read its description? can it pick from your other list at indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each sublist, then for each index get the corresponding value (also don't use `list` built-in name as variable name)

```
results = [[values[sub_idx][item] for item in sublist] for sub_idx, sublist in enumerate(index_list)]
```

## [`CODE DEMO`](https://repl.it/repls/MatureThirdStaff)

Comment: Thank you for your help and advice!